# Understanding markov chains in the brms package's brm function

Tags: markov-chains

I am trying to use the brms package's brm function to fit bayesian mixed effect models. The documentation isnt very clear on what exactly is achieved by increasing the number of chains, number of iterations and warmup. It would be helpful if someone can help explain these.

```
brmmod <- brm(
  data = modeling_input,
  formula = brm_formula,
  prior = brm_prior,
  cores = 1, chains = 4, iter = 1000, warmup = 500
)
```

I have realized that increasing the number of cores to equal the number of chains gives me the least run time.

I want to understand:
a) how will increasing the value of iter and warmup parameters help me.
b) If I increase the number of Markov chains, how does it impact the model?
c) If I spin a machine equal to the number of chains parameter, would that give me the best performance in terms of runtime? My current model with cores = 1 takes 3 days to run. I however changed the cores to 4 and didn't change any other parameters. This helped me bring down the runtime to 2 days.

I am new to this so appreciate some help. Happy to read any good material or blog post. Have tried to find more details but the documentation isnt very helpful.

It can be found here (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/brms.pdf) and the page number to reference is Pg 27.